# With The Last Man

Tags: chess

Here’s a nifty little problem. It’s White to move and mate in 12! Don’t forget to explain the title!

**Johann Christoffel Van Gool, Le Journal de Genève 1979**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the last man is:

> The c3 pawn,

If:

> 1. Nfe6+ d7xe6 2. Nxe6+ fxe6 3. Bxf6+ Kxf6 4. Rxf4+ gxf4 5. Qf8+ Ke5 6. Qxf4+ Kd5 7. Qg5+ Re5 8. e4+ Bxe4 9. Qd2+ Rxd2 10. Ba2+ Rxa2 11. Rd4+ cxd4 12. c4#

(I think this line is forced step by step, that`s why I did not include any further explanation. Obviously after sacrificing all, the last piece left for white is the pawn that eventually mates.)